# Снимок с камеры в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt

Необходимо, чтобы при запуске программы сохранялось два снимка с вебкамеры, но сохраняется только первый снимок.

```
import sys        
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):            
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)            
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()            
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        self.layout.insertWidget(1, self.viewfinder)
        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start() 
            self.capture = QCameraImageCapture(self.camera)
        # Сохранение снимков
        for i in range(2):                                
            self.capture.capture('C:/pyqt_' + str(i) + '.jpg')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("pyqt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: А если `for i in range(3)` сделать, сколько сохранит?

Comment: @Сергей Кох сохраняет один раз

Comment: Наверное, последнюю?

Comment: @Сергей Кох сохраняет нулевую (т.е. первую по порядку). Я предполагаю, что внутри команды 'self.capture.capture()' заложено, что-то вроде 'break', которая прерывает цикл, но даже если ввожу без цикла, например три раза повторяю строку, тоже делает одно сохранение. Ещё заметил, что, если присвоить строку 'self.capture.capture()' переменной, например 'a' и потом вывести её значение, то появляется порядковый номер снимка, т.е. для цикла 'for i in range(3):' если поместить в цикл 'a = self.capture.capture()', то 'print(a)' будет последовательно выводить 1, 2, 3. Не знаю для чего, но просто заметил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**readyForCapture**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraimagecapture.html#readyForCapture-prop) : const bool
>
> Это свойство определяет, готова ли служба немедленно захватить изображение. 
> Вызов `capture()`, когда значение `ReadyForCapture` имеет значение **`false`**, не разрешен и приводит к ошибке.

Вставьте принт в свой цикл и вы все увидите:

```
    for i in range(2):                                
        print(f'{self.capture.isReadyForCapture()}')        # <----
        self.capture.capture(f'D:/_Qt/__Qt/pyqt_{i}.jpg')
```

Вам надо менять логику, например так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import * 


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):            
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.cameraInfo = QCameraInfo.defaultCamera()            
        self.camera = QCamera(self.cameraInfo)
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        
        self.i = 0                                                        # +++
        self.capture = QCameraImageCapture(self.camera)
        self.capture.readyForCaptureChanged.connect(self.captureChanged)  # +++
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.layout.insertWidget(1, self.viewfinder)
        if self.camera.status() != QCamera.UnavailableStatus:
            self.camera.start() 
#            self.capture = QCameraImageCapture(self.camera)

    def captureChanged(self, ready):                                        # +++
        if ready and self.i < 5:            # для теста, хотим сделать 5(пять) снимков 
            print(f'  captureChanged: {ready}') #
            self.capture.capture(f'D:/_Qt/__Qt/pyqt_{self.i}.jpg')
            self.i += 1
        
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("PyQt5 QCameraImageCapture")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```